# Debugging SOAP Transmission

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, indy

I am attempting to do a proof-of-concept consumption of a web service using Delphi 2010 and Indy.  My code at this point is:

```
procedure TForm1.Log(const sEvent, sMsg: String);
const sPrior: String = '';
begin
  if sEvent <> sPrior then begin
    mTraffic.Lines.Append('');
    mTraffic.Lines.Append(Format('%s: %s', [sEvent, FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss.zzz', Now)]));
    mTraffic.Lines.Append('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
    sPrior := sEvent;
  end;
  mTraffic.Lines.Append(sMsg);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

function TForm1.BuildRequest: String;
const MINPERDAY = 1440;
var slRequest: TStringList;
    sFileName: String;
    sID: String;
    sGUID: String;
    oDoc: TNativeXML;
    oNode: TXmlNode;
    uNow: _SystemTime;
    dtNow: TDateTime;
    sNow: String;
    sNonce: String;
    oIdmd5: TIdHashMessageDigest5;
begin
  sFileName := 'Send.xml';
  slRequest := TStringList.Create;
  oIdmd5 := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
  oDoc := TNativeXML.Create;
  try
    oDoc.LoadFromFile(sFileName);
    SetAttrib(oDoc, 'inputMessage', 'utc', FormatDateTime('m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm', Now));
    sGUID := 'urn:uuid' + MyCreateUUID;
    SetAttrib(oDoc, 'inputMessage', 'messageId', sGUID);
    SetNode(oDoc, 'wsa:messageId', sGUID);
    Windows.GetSystemTime(uNow);
    dtNow := SysUtils.SystemTimeToDateTime(uNow);
    sNow := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh:mm:ss"Z"', dtNow);
    sNonce := oIdmd5.HashStringAsHex(sNow + 'Jack' + 'Test' + 'Salt');
    SetNodes(oDoc, 'wsu:Created', FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh:mm:ss"Z"', dtNow));
    SetNode(oDoc, 'wsu:Expires', FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh:mm:ss"Z"', dtNow + 5 /MINPERDAY));
    SetNode(oDoc, 'wsse:Nonce', sNonce);
    SetNode(oDoc, 'ElectronicPostmark', FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh:mm:ss.zz-8.00', dtNow));
    SetNode(oDoc, 'wsse:Username', '#MyUserName#');
    SetNode(oDoc, 'wsse:Password', '#MyPassword#');
    oDoc.XmlFormat := xfReadable;
    Result := oDoc.WriteToString;
  finally
    slRequest.Free;
    oIdmd5.Free;
    oDoc.Free;
  end;

end;

function TForm1.SSLPost(const url: String; sRequest: String): String;
var lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
    lIOHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    lIDLogDebug: TIdLogDebug;
    ss: TStringStream;
begin
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  lIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  lIDLogDebug := TIdLogDebug.Create(nil);
  ss := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    ss.WriteString(sRequest);
    ss.Position := 0;
    lIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
    lIOHandler.OnStatusInfo := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1StatusInfo;
    lHTTP.IOHandler := lIOHandler;
    lIdLogDebug.OnSend := IdLogDebug1Send;
    lIDLogDebug.OnReceive := IdLogDebug1Receive;
    lIDLogDebug.Active := True;
    lHTTP.Intercept := lIdLogDebug;
    try
      lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('SOAPAction: "http://edd.ca.gov/SendTransmission"');
      Result := lHTTP.Post(url, ss);
    except
      On e: Exception do begin
        Result := e.Message + #13#10 + '**No Response**';
      end;
    end;
  finally
    lHTTP.Free;
    lIOHandler.Free;
    lIdLogDebug.Free;
    ss.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var sResponse: String;
begin
  sResponse := SSLPost('https://FSETTESTPROD.EDD.CA.GOV', BuildRequest);
  Log('Response', sResponse);
end;
```

Note: I am particularly uncertain about this line just before the POST

```
lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('SOAPAction: "http://edd.ca.gov/SendTransmission"');
```

According to the web service documentation, I should be getting either an ACK1 success or an ACK1 error with an explanation.  Here is the result I am getting at this point:

```
    SSL: 02/28/2012 16:33:55.609
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
    SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
    SSL status: "SSLv3 write client hello A"
    SSL status: "SSLv3 read server hello A"
    SSL status: "SSLv3 read server certificate A"
    SSL status: "SSLv3 read server done A"
    SSL status: "SSLv3 write client key exchange A"
    SSL status: "SSLv3 write change cipher spec A"
    SSL status: "SSLv3 write finished A"
    SSL status: "SSLv3 flush data"
    SSL status: "SSLv3 read finished A"
    SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
    SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
    Cipher: name = RC4-MD5; description = RC4-MD5                 SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=MD5 
    ; bits = 128; version = TLSv1/SSLv3; 

    Send: 02/28/2012 16:33:55.859
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    POST / HTTP/1.0
    Content-Length: 3130
    SOAPAction: "http://edd.ca.gov/SendTransmission"
    Host: FSETTESTPROD.EDD.CA.GOV
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding: identity
    User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <log>
      <inputMessage utc="2/28/2012 04:32:28 pm" messageId="urn:uuid{4A995507-9E23-49C3-A17C-19C30693C6C1}">
        <processingStep description="Unprocessed message">
          <soap:Envelope xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <soap:Header>
              <wsa:Action>http://edd.ca.gov/Sendtransmission</wsa:Action>
              <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid{4A995507-9E23-49C3-A17C-19C30693C6C1}</wsa:MessageID>
              <wsa:ReplyTo>
                <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
              </wsa:ReplyTo>
              <wsa:To>http://localhost:3031/EDD.DMRC.FSET.WebServices/FsetService.asmx</wsa:To>
              <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
                <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-db31b09e-9283-4ff1-9a57-5b97971328d4">
                  <wsu:Created>2012-02-29T00:32:28Z</wsu:Created>
                  <wsu:Expires>2012-02-29T00:37:28Z</wsu:Expires>
                </wsu:Timestamp>
                <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-0ac2cf06-b8da-46c8-9314-8081144b09d5">
                  <wsse:Username>#MyUserName#</wsse:Username>
                  <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">#MyPassword#</wsse:Password>
                  <wsse:Nonce>0D78327F3F671183149EEC5907A6A5F6</wsse:Nonce>
                  <wsu:Created>2012-02-29T00:32:28Z</wsu:Created>
                </wsse:UsernameToken>
              </wsse:Security>
            </soap:Header>
            <soap:Body>
              <SendTransmission xmlns="http://edd.ca.gov/">
                <SendTransmissionRequest xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/a2a/mef/MeFTransmitterServiceWse.xsd">
                  <transmissionDataList>
                    <Count>1</Count>
                    <transmissionData>
                      <transmissionId>123456789</transmissionId>
                      <ElectronicPostmark>2012-02-29T00:32:28.750-8.00</ElectronicPostmark>
                    </transmissionData>
                  </transmissionDataList>
                </SendTransmissionRequest>
                <fileBytes>UEsDBBQAAAAIAAaJUzYwks2W0QYAAD2IAAALAAAAREU2</fileBytes>
              </SendTransmission>
            </soap:Body>
          </soap:Envelope>
        </processingStep>
      </inputMessage>
    </log>

Receive: 02/28/2012 16:33:56.234
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 29 Feb 2012 00:33:51 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 195
Content-Type: text/html
Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDCQSQQDSS=BPLHDJLCKCLDKBDMLBNJOMHP; path=/
Cache-control: private

<html>
<head>
<title>This location has been marked as available</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>AVAILABLE</h1>
This IP address has been assigned to EDD FSET User Test web site.
</body>
</html>

Response: 02/28/2012 16:33:56.281
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<html>
<head>
<title>This location has been marked as available</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>AVAILABLE</h1>
This IP address has been assigned to EDD FSET User Test web site.
</body>
</html>
```

I have been in phone and email contact with the agency that maintains the web service (the California EDD).  They are motivated to get as many people as possible to adopt this technology and reduce the amount of paper they have to handle but their they don't have in depth knowledge of the system because it was created by an outside vendor.

I have downloaded SOAPUI to try to understand the service better and eliminate any errors that might be caused by my implementation and possible misuse of the Indy library.  I'm not sure how to use SOAPUI for this purpose.  The instructions don't seem to address my situation.  If I load the WSDL into the program and attempt to test one of the functions, I get the result that the test finished with status [FINISHED] and I don't know what to make of that.

I would appreciate any help on my little problem.

Comment: 1st, it's not "a little problem", from what I understand you have virtually no documentation, try importing the WSDL into Delphi and work your way from there, if Delphi's WSDL Importer will import it, then we might be able to work with that...

Comment: @Dorin I agree that it is not a little problem.  That was an attempt to maintain perspective.  When I first started this process I used the WSDL Importer to build my client.  That was pretty early in this process.  I did not understand web communications well and hiding parts of it while trying to understand and debug my process seemed counter productive.  When I read of other users finding that the WSDL Importer had problems and did an incomplete job, I abandoned it in favor of a more basic approach that I thought I could follow better.

Comment: from my past experience with Delphi WSDL Importer, I can assure you that it's not easy, but the first step is using SOAP UI to test some functions, then SAVE the "Request/Response" from SOAP UI, using delphi's wsdl importer and attempt the to get the same request/response or similar, then I think we can help, but it won't be easy, that's for sure ):

Comment: What does the WSDL say is the endpoint URL? If you aren't sure, when you import the WSDL into SoapUI it will be the URL that it tries to submit to. It's listed in the dropdown box just above the request and response frames in SoapUI. My hunch is that the URL you are posting to (https://FSETTESTPROD.EDD.CA.GOV) is not the web service endpoint.

Comment: @Sam Thanks for responding.  In the object inspector under the test cases, there is an option to set the endpoint.  It apparently picked the address up from the WSDL.  The URL offered is https://fsettestprod.edd.ca.gov/fsetproxy/fsetservice.asmx.  That is not exactly the same as where I have been instructed to send the message which is the address you are showing.  It's a drop down list control that does not allow editing.

Comment: @jrodenhi The dropdown list should allow you to edit. There should be an option that says [edit current..] near the bottom of the dropdown list. Are you able to post a URL to the WSDL here? I'm happy to try it out in SoapUI.

Comment: @Sam It may be that you are on to something there.  In email messages I have from EDD, they are saying to use the address you are showing above.  The WSDL file shows the extension of that address that I mentioned in my last comment.  I edited the XML to get rid of the ?s as Chris suggested. When I send that test case using SOAPUI to the address as instructed, I get some HTML that says "This IP address has been assigned to EDD FSET User Test web site". When I send it to the WSDL address, I get "Bad Request".  I probably messed up the XML.  I will look there next.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SoapUI is the way to go, to see how things should work.  Use the RIO.OnBeforeExecute and AfterExecute events to examine the XML that you're sending and receiving. Compare those to what SoapUI sends and receives. Ignore differences in namespaces, which shouldn't matter. Ideally, you should be able to take the XML coming out of the OnBeforeExecute event (save the stream to a text file or log), paste  into SoapUI, (right-click to clean-up/reformat in SoapUI) and see if the XML makes sense, and see what happens when you submit that.

If it turns out that your XML is close to working, but a 'tweak' is needed, you can edit the XML in the OnBeforeExecute event with StringReplace, etc., and 'fix' the XML so it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Chris.  This is going to be the process I follow now.  I still have another problem but I need to open another question for it.